# prevent line break after specific word (php)

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a long text and I would like to add a no-wrap after specific key words. Lets say: 'Mr.', 'the', 'an' the only problem is I do not know what word will be after the key. 
So if I have a text like:

```
... there is an elephant in the room ...
```

script should change it to:

```
... there is <span class="no-wrap">an elephant</span> in <span class="no-wrap"> the room</span> ...
```

I know that it should be done with regular expression of some sort but I am really bad at those. So any tips on how to do this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture `Mr.`, `the`, `an` strings and also the following word into a group.

```
(\b(?:Mr\.|the|an)\h+\S+)
```

Replacement string:

```
<span class="no-wrap">$1</span>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sK7kB4/2)

Code:

```
<?php
$string = "... there is an elephant in the room ...";
echo preg_replace('~(\b(?:Mr\.|the|an)\h+\S+)~', '<span class="no-wrap">$1</span>', $string)
?>
```

Output:

```
... there is <span class="no-wrap">an elephant</span> in <span class="no-wrap">the room</span> ...
```

Comment: use `\h*` incase of spaces may or maynot occur `((?:Mr\.|the|an)\h*\S+)`